# Jquery Filter <li> on Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, jquery-ui-multiselect

I tried to create a filter, which displays li-elements, based on the selected options. It works, when I select just one option, the elements show up when selected and disappear when deselected.

But when multiple option are selected, the elements first appear and then disappear again. I guess something in the loop is wrong?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Hide all li-Elements
  $(".result li").hide();

  //When select-Element is change, do something
  $("select").change(function() {

    //Create array for selected Options 
    var arr = new Array;

    //Add all selected Options to the array
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
      arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    //Create a Loop to display li-Elements
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {

      /*slideDown all elements which contain one
          of the selected elements in array*/
      $("li:contains(" + arr[i] + ")").slideDown("slow");
      /*slideUp all elements which do not contain
          the selected elements in array*/
      $('li:not(:contains(' + arr[i] + '))').slideUp("slow");
    }
  });

});
```

Html:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">saab</option>
  <option value="opel">opel</option>
  <option value="audi">audi</option>
</select>

<div class="result">
  <ul>
    <li>volvo</li>
    <li>volvo coolio</li>
    <li>saab</li>
    <li>opel</li>
    <li>opelino</li>
    <li>opel meier</li>
    <li>audi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Preview: https://jsfiddle.net/onclesam/2z56oom2/3/

Comment: It's because in the first loop you look for say 'volvo' and display it. the next loop, the value is not 'volvo' so you hide it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in each iteration you are resetting the filter, instead you can do

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Hide all li-Elements
  var $lis = $(".result li").hide();

  //When select-Element is change, do something
  $("select").change(function() {

    //Add all selected Options to the array
    var selectors = $("select option:selected").map(function(i, value) {
      return ':contains("' + this.value + '")'
    }).get();
    var $selected = $lis.stop().filter(selectors.join()).slideDown();
    $lis.not($selected).slideUp();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">saab</option>
  <option value="opel">opel</option>
  <option value="audi">audi</option>
</select>

<div class="result">
  <ul>
    <li>volvo</li>
    <li>volvo coolio</li>
    <li>saab</li>
    <li>opel</li>
    <li>opelino</li>
    <li>opel meier</li>
    <li>audi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you iterate through the selected options then:

- Show the selected option.
- Hide the other options.

With this login in mind, when iterating through multiple options only the last one will be displayed.

In the example below you can see your own code modified in the way that it first hides all the options, only the, it shows the selected ones.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //Hide all li-Elements
 $(".result li").hide();

 //When select-Element is change, do something
 $("select").change(function(){

  //Create array for selected Options 
  var arr = new Array;
   
   //Add all selected Options to the array
  $("select option:selected").each  ( function() {
   arr.push ( $(this).val() );
  });
  
  // Hidding all elements.
  $('li').slideUp("slow"); 
  
  //Create a Loop to display li-Elements
  for ( var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++ ) {
   // Showing selected items.
   $( "li:contains("+ arr[ i ] +")" ).slideDown("slow");
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">saab</option>
  <option value="opel">opel</option>
  <option value="audi">audi</option>
</select> 

<div class="result">
 <ul>
  <li>volvo</li>
  <li>volvo coolio</li>
  <li>saab</li>
  <li>opel</li>
  <li>opelino</li>
  <li>opel meier</li>
  <li>audi</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2z56oom2/4/